# string similarity metrics between n strings

Tags: mysql, string

I have a mysql database with about 10 million publication titles.
Now when I want to add a new title, chances are that the title already exists, but written slightly different.
One example:

```
Overview on +-Trees....
Overview on B-Tree .....
Overview on $({\rm B}^+)$-Trees....
```

All 3 titles are different, if I'm trying to match them exactly but they refer to the same publication.

Now I could use something like levenshtein for the calculation of similarity.
But with 10 Million+ titles it might take too long to calculate each distance.

Now what I was thinking was, whether there is some kind of metric that I could apply on all strings as a precalculation. 
For example calculate the amount of words so that I only gather titles with similar word length. The goal would be to reduce the amount of levenshtein comparisions from 10 Million to 100.000 or less.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for exaction string by using BINARY in mysql. It will give results as whether it matched exactly or not

```
 select * from table where BINARY column_name = "matching_value";
```